# Generate SSL key and cert in Windows

Tags: windows, ssl, kibana

According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/kibana.html, 
I need to set

```
server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key
server.ssl.cert: /path/to/your/server.crt
```

Where could I find the path for the key and cert in Windows Environment? Or how should I make one and find the key and path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to generate your own self-signed certificate or request a certificate to a Trusted Authority. After this you will get the .key (the private key of the certificate) and .crt (the public part of the certificate)

To create a self signed certificate follow this link [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

You will need openssl

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key
openssl req -sha256 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj "/CN=localhost"
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Replace 'localhost' with your domain name. Run commands one by one because openssl will prompt you same values for certificate generation

If you need a trusted certificate, request one to a trusted authority like letsencrypt.org

Comment: I have use cygwin64 to run those commancds but I could not find back where those keys and certs have been created at.

Comment: I do not know where is the HOME directory of cygwin. Try this link http://www.voxforge.org/home/docs/cygwin-cheat-sheet or this http://superuser.com/questions/388397/how-do-i-change-the-default-startup-directory-in-cygwin or look for openssl `openssl version -d`

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot. Great thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kennedy Kan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark or upvote  if it has been helpful

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help.